# If $a|c$ and $b|d$, is it true that $ab|cd$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Determine if this is true or not:

> For any natural numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, if $a | c$ and $b | d$ then $ab|cd$.

My answer was **True**, I went:

> $a = 2$, $b = 4$, $c = 6$, and $d = 8$.
>
> If $2|6$ and $4|8$, then $(2 * 4) | (6 * 8)$.

Is there another way to do it using, for example, a contradiction proof?

Comment: You haven't proved the assertion. You've just found one example where it's true. You need algebra for the general case. Start with: if $a | c$ then there is an integer $x$ such that $c = ax$. Then ...

Comment: You haven't done anything yet. You claimed something, but you didn't prove it. Your example is not a proof.

Comment: You can't prove by giving an example.  But an example can give you ideas of how to do it.  What is $a|c$ *mean*?  It means $c = ka$ for some integer $k$.  So $b|d$ means $d = jb$ for some integer $j$.  So what is $c*d$ equal to?

Answer (score 5):

The claim is that this is True for *any* numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.  So, unlike the counterexample you asked about earlier, where you only had to find one example where the claim fails, if you want to prove that this is True, you want to prove that this is true in general, i.e. for *all* numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, and not just for some specific numbers.

So: Take any numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, and suppose $a|c$ and $b|d$. Now, if $a|c$ then that means that $c = ae$ for some whole number $e$. Likewise, $d = bf$ for some whole number $f$.  Hence, $cd = aebf = abef$. Hence, there is some whole number $g =ef$ such that $cd =abg$. Hence, $ab|cd$.